# Как запомнить позицию элемента в ArrayList после перемещения

Tags: java, android

Приложение на основе [Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo).

Имеется `ArrayList` с изображениями.

Есть возможность перемещать изображения.

После выхода из приложения элементы списка принимают первоначальное положение.

Как запомнить позицию элемента после перемещения и выхода из приложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В адаптере есть поле `List<String> mItems`, в котором хранятся данные, которые выводятся в `RecyclerView`. При изменении порядка элементов в `RecyclerView` изменяется и порядок элементов в `mItems`.

Для сохранения порядка элементов Вам необходимо каким-либо образом сохранять список `mItems` при выходе из приложения и загружать сохраненный список в `mItems` при старте приложения.

Список `mItems` можно сохранить, например, просто в файл. Также можно использовать другие подходы для сохранения этих данных, но в бОльшей степени это зависит от архитектуры Вашего приложения.